# Javascript doesn't work in IE, works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, keydown

I can't find why the following doesn't work in IE but works in Chrome. In IE11 I can't get the orange square to move with my keyboard, it's static in the upperleft corner. In chrome it works perfectly.
Do I need to use different methods?

```
<style type="text/css">
#sprite1 {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #ffd800;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sprite1"></div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="output"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var xVal = 0;
    var yVal = 0;
    var sprite = document.getElementById("sprite1");
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "X: 0" + " Y: 0";
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 37) {
            x -= 5;
            xVal = x + "px";
            sprite.style.left = xVal;
        }
        if (event.keyCode == 38) {
            y -= 5;
            yVal = y + "px";
            sprite.style.top = yVal;
        }
        if (event.keyCode == 39) {
            x += 5;
            xVal = x + "px";
            sprite.style.left = xVal;
        }
        if (event.keyCode == 40) {
            y += 5;
            yVal = y + "px";
            sprite.style.top = yVal;
        }
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "X: " + xVal + " Y: " + yVal;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What do you see in the F12 dev tools? What do you see when you step through the code statement by statement in the debugger built into IE11?

Comment: It works for me on IE 11 https://jsfiddle.net/kktmatax/

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me ?

Comment: Works for me in IE11 too - https://jsfiddle.net/sjzs6hwy/

Comment: If you swap to window instead of document?

Comment: In the debugger I do see the following exception:
object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'
I am working on this in my work environment, could they have configured some settings that disable some of these methods?